# Applescript Crashing on Infinite Loop

Tags: terminal, applescript, crash

I am trying to use applescript to wait for a Serial keyword (in Screen - in Terminal), and then pausePlay Spotify when the keyword is seen.  It works fine at first, but then quickly crashes.  Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

I am sorry, but I can't seem to get the Applescript code to format properly here...
Here is the Applescript code:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set the bounds of window 1 to {0, 0, 500, 100}
end tell

set trigger to 1

set stopString to ""

repeat until (stopString = "stop")

    tell application "Terminal"

        if the contents of window 1 contains "Start MP3" and trigger is 1 then
            tell application "Spotify" to playpause
            set trigger to 0
        end if

        if the contents of window 1 does not contain "Start MP3" then
            set trigger to 1
        end if

        if the contents of window 1 contains "Stop Loop" then
            set stopString to "stop"
        end if


    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: What do you mean by crashing, exactly?  Is anything interesting in the console log when it crashes? What you have looks reasonable to me. I tested it on my system and it worked okay. I didn't see any crashes. I would recommend a "delay 1" before the final end repeat, to cut down on the CPU usage. Right now, it hogs the CPU.  Caveat: I don't have Spotify, so I changed that to iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now having Screen output to log.txt, and the following applescript works just great!

set trigger to 1

set stopString to ""

repeat until (stopString = "stop")

```
set testTxt to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/fed/log.txt")
set countTxt to (count of testTxt) - 1
set lastLine to item countTxt of testTxt    
if lastLine contains "Start MP3" and trigger is 1 then
    tell application "Spotify" to playpause
    set trigger to 0
end if

if lastLine does not contain "Start MP3" then
    set trigger to 1
end if

if lastLine contains "Stop Loop" then
    set stopString to "stop"
end if
```

end repeat

Answer (score 0):

Like all while/do (Applescript repeat) loops, you must ensure a condition is met for it to exit.

How do you ensure that a condition will be met and not go on infinitely?  From what I can tell you have a window that can contain "Start MP3" or "Stop Loop."  What if it contains "I love balloons" or is blank?

You haven't created any logic for this (error trapping) so this loop will repeat until the window meets the condition to stop.

To prevent that you to put in a fail safe that sets the condition that stops the loop.  You can do this  by adding a counter and checking the counter against a predetermined value that will force condition that stops the loop to become true.

For example, we set a limit that the loop will run 10 times:

```
set count to 0

repeat until (stopString = "stop")

    ...


    if count > 10 then
        set stopString to "stop"
    end if

    set count to count + 1

end repeat
```

Comment: But I't like the loop to go on for a long time, waiting for one of the 2 input "Start MP3" or "Stop Loop." Sometimes the wait may be 10 or more minutes.  Can that be done?

Comment: You can do anything, you just have to define the parameters ***specifically*** as to what you want to happen.  You also have to define what you want to have happen if those conditions are never met; this is why you have an infinite loop - the stop condition is never met.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.  I thought I did make a stop condition by including the stopString.  Also, how can I make the stop condition 30 minutes?  Thanks for your help so far.